# MongoDB auth=true clusterAdmin still has lack of priveleges

Tags: linux, mongodb, authentication, ubuntu, permissions

I need a little help with mongo.

I installed 2.4.9 version from accroding to this instructions:
For ubuntu - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/
For Debian - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/

I followed manuals and documentation. Everything worked fine but when I change mongo settings to "auth=true" permissions go crazy.

Here is my user:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5305dd8729ae7b95a4bde944"),
    "user" : "root",
    "pwd" : "063bbfd478f7b78df6c93b6202af9145",
    "roles" : ["clusterAdmin", "userAdminAnyDatabase", 
            "readWriteAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase" ] }
```

I used rockmongo. And when I open my mongodb it says that I don't have enough permissions to run command **db.getCollectionNames()**

It says: **Execute failed:unauthorized**

And the same thing for creating users, managing databases.

I can't imagine what more permissions should I provide to user.

As it is said in manual this user is the first one I created. I gave him all highest admin privileges.

After changing **auth** parameter to **auth=true**
I also can't login in command line.

```
$ mongo -uroot -p <my password> --host 127.0.0.1
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
Thu Feb 20 11:56:17.510 Error: 18 { code: 18, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth fails" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:228
exception: login failed
```

By the way I tried password with and without braces. With long option and short one. This way **-p<my password>** and this way **-p <my password>**

But application (use simple db users) works fine.
I created database and two users (before making auth=true) and they seems fine for applications that use them.

I couldn't google any information. In most cases adding **clusterAdmin** or other permissions solves the problem for them.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian 7 (In both same behavior)
MongoDb: 2.4.9

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the user on the admin database?
clusterAdmin and the *AnyDatabase permissions apply only on the admin database.

When you authenticate, you'll need to authenticate against the admin database and then access other databases according to user's permissions.

`mongo --authenticationDatabase admin -u root -p <my password> --host 127.0.0.1`

Comment: >"Did you create the user on the admin database?"
Yes I did.
And it's single server configuration I just need clusterAdmin to manage it remotely.

Comment: You are authenticating against the "test" database as you can see in the response `connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test`, try like this: `mongo --authenticationDatabase admin -u root -p <my password> --host 127.0.0.1`